# Aldebaran's NAO robot variable list

Tags: python, battery, nao-robot

I am trying to make a short script in Python that would give me the battery charge as well as the battery status (in charge or not in charge) and the state (on/off) of NAO robots in a given local network.

To do that I am looking for a list of all variables (including sensor variables) that characterizes my NAO robot. I found the [list of all callable events](https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/doc/1-14/naoqi-eventindex.html) and a [list of Memory Keys](https://community.aldebaran-robotics.com/doc/1-14/naoqi-memoryindex.html) but no variable list. I am looking in particuliar for a `BatteryCharge` variable if such a variable exists.

Does such a list exist? If not, how should I proceed to do what I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for your answers, but I found a way to get the complete list of data accessible through an ALMemory proxy.

`print("ALMemory device keys...")
for key in memoryProxy.getDataListName():
    print(key)
print("\n\n")`

So the variable I was looking for was indeed `Device/SubDeviceList/Battery/Charge/Sensor/Value`

Answer (score 0):

I found this on Aldebaran's website...

int getBatteryLevel ()

Get the battery level (0..5) 5: full 0: totally empty (never reached).
Returns
the battery level (0..5): 5: full 0: totally empty (never reached)

string getBatteryLevelDesc ()

Get a text presentation of the battery level ('My battery is...').
Returns the sentence describing the battery level

Let me know if it helps

Comment: Is that a C++ method ? If so is there any equivalent for Python ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. This is python- battery.append(memory.getData(key))

Answer (score 0):

There's no list, but you can get access in one call to a list of wanted variable.
eg:

```
mem = ALProxy( "ALMemory" )
listData = [
              "Device/SubDeviceList/Battery/Current/Sensor/Value",
              "Device/SubDeviceList/Battery/Charge/Sensor/Status",
              "Device/SubDeviceList/Battery/Charge/Sensor/Value",
           ]

listVal = mem.getListData( listData )
```